# How to find JSON string in HTML file

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I'm trying to find a plaintext JSON within a webpage, using Javascript. The JSON will appear as plaintext as seen in the browser, but it is possible that it would be truncated into separate html tags. Example:

```html
<div>
{"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"mZT_XuM9Lwn0j7O_YNWN_f7S_J6sLxcQuWsRVBlAM3_5S5aD0yWGV78B-Gti2MrqWwuAhb_6SkBlOvEF8-UCHR_rgZhVR1qbrxvQLE_zpamGJbFU_c1Vm8hEAvMt9ZltEGFS22BHBW079ebWI3PoDdS-DJvjjtszFdnkIZpn4oav9fzz0
</div>
<div>
xIaaxp6-qQFjKXCboun5pto59eJnn-bJl1D3LloCw7rSEYQr1x5mxhIxAFVVsNGuE9fjk0ueTDcMUbFLPYn6PopDMuN0T1B2D1Y8ClItEVbVDFb-mRPz8THJ_gexJ8C20n8m-pBlpL4WyyPuY2ScDugmfG7UnBGrDmS5w"}
</div>
```

I've tried to use this RegEx.

```regex
{"?\w+"?:[^}<]+(?:(?:(?:<\/[^>]+>)[^}<]*(?:<[^>]+>)+)*[^}<]*)*}
```

But the problem is it fails to work with nested JSON.

I may also use javascript to count the number of `{` and `}` to find where the JSON actually ends, but there must be better options than using this slow and clumsy approach.

Many thanks

---

Update: 
Perhaps there ain't better way to do this. Below is my current code (a bit verbose but probably needed):

```
let regex = /{[\s\n]*"\w+"[\s\n]*:/g;

// Consider both open and close curly brackets
let brackets = /[{}]/g;

let arr0, arr;
// Try to parse every matching JSON
arr0 = match.exec(body);
if (arr0 === null) { // Nothing found
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
}

try {
    brackets.lastIndex = match.lastIndex; // After beginning of current JSON
    let count = 1;
    // Count for { and } to find the end of JSON.
    while ((count !== 0) && ((arr = brackets.exec(body)) !== null)) {
        count += (arr[0] === "{" ? 1 : -1);
    }

    // If nothing special, complete JSON found when count === 0;
    let lastIdx = brackets.lastIndex;
    let json = body.substring(match.lastIndex - arr0[0].length, lastIdx);

    try {
        let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
     // Process the JSON here to get the original message
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(err);
    }

...

} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
};
```

Comment: A general solution without constraints would be hard. Maybe search for elements whose `textContent` starts with `{`, then evaluate it, followed by its next sibling if it doesn't parse, etc. Don't use a regular expression

Comment: @CertainPerformance Unfortunately in my case the JSON doesn't always appear at the beginning of an element, but luckily they all start with the same element (which I'd be searching for; the code above is generalized a bit). So for now I'd still go for counting brackets...

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible in a good way, it might be possible to take a parent element's innerText and parse that:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(document.getElementById('outer').innerText.replace(/\s|\n/g, '')));
```

```html
<div id="outer">
<div>
{"kty":"RSA","e":"AQAB","n":"mZT_XuM9Lwn0j7O_YNWN_f7S_J6sLxcQuWsRVBlAM3_5S5aD0yWGV78B-Gti2MrqWwuAhb_6SkBlOvEF8-UCHR_rgZhVR1qbrxvQLE_zpamGJbFU_c1Vm8hEAvMt9ZltEGFS22BHBW079ebWI3PoDdS-DJvjjtszFdnkIZpn4oav9fzz0
</div>
<div>
xIaaxp6-qQFjKXCboun5pto59eJnn-bJl1D3LloCw7rSEYQr1x5mxhIxAFVVsNGuE9fjk0ueTDcMUbFLPYn6PopDMuN0T1B2D1Y8ClItEVbVDFb-mRPz8THJ_gexJ8C20n8m-pBlpL4WyyPuY2ScDugmfG7UnBGrDmS5w"}
</div>
</div>
```

But it's likely to fail sometimes

Comment: I obviously overlooked `.innerText` when I said I need to filter the html tag, but seems like I still need to count `{` and `}` after all.